# Android: Edittext advance filter for searching in listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `EditText` and a `ListView` right now i am filtering the listview with the help of the text in edit text by using method `contains(someString)`. But actually i want to search in the scenario where like edit text has text i.e. `ABC Product`. Now i want the search to show all the rows with either `ABC` or `Product` in it. Say for example the list with the above mentioned search will show `ABC Item` and `XYZ Product`. Is there any default method for this or i have to use custom functionality for this.

Comment: We'll not exactly default, but you'll have to perform `contains()` twice. What I mean is if you `split()` the search string (from the `EditText` on the space " " symbol), you can have the two words, then perform `contains()` for each one of them. Give an example here and I can show it to you.

Comment: yes goody got you, i was thinking of something like that but i thought there may be some default functionality available.

Comment: Well default - I wouldn't say so, because the basic methods are provided and you can use them in any combination. The thing you need is not a standart functionnality. If the answer Helped you I can paste it like an Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not exactly default, but you'll have to perform contains() twice.
What I mean is if you `split()` the search string (from the `EditText` on the space " " symbol), you can have the two words, then perform `contains()` for each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

inputSearchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
             // When user changed the Text
             YourActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```